# What do you call this image effect and how is it achieved?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, photo-editing

[image]

I've been trying to describe this effect on google and got no useful results. Seems like its a mix between a tint via the overlay and the offset?

[Here](http://postimg.org/image/6e45pxlif/) is another example, but the effect seems less pronounced.

Comment: Looks like a gradient overlay to me.

Comment: There is a lens flare effect overlayed as well.

Answer (score 8):

As per my comment, this effect can easily be made with a gradient.

Below is an image that has had a `Gradient Map` applied (purple & orange) and had the blending mode set to `Screen`.

The potency of the effect is determined by the colors as well as the opacity. Playing around with different blending modes may also lead to some other cool results.
[image]

Comment: @Dominic I can't, because it's not my question :)

Answer (score 2):

Without testing, the result on the image you provided looks as achievable with :

1. decreasing saturation
2. applying cold photo filter
3. adjusting shadows and highlights
4. little bit of surface blur
5. little bit of sharpness in the end