# How to recreate a common startup trend — tinted background image

Tags: color, layers, images, background

I'm trying to create a design for a startup I'm involved with where there's a background image that's been tinted by a colour.

Examples of what I'm looking to recreate include the background header for [sendtoinc](http://sendtoinc.com) and [this image on the acorns blog](http://blog.acorns.com/image/86542967072)

[image]

I'm struggling to get the correct settings to balance the brand colours and the background image without it looking way too contrasting or looking stupid. Ideally, I'd love to have a little bit of colour come through in the background, but not too much as to affect the brand colour (similar to the image in the sendtoinc header).

Many thanks to you guys in advance!

Comment: Could you describe what you've tried so far? Your examples don't look too different from a simple photo at around 20% opacity over the gradient.

Comment: David pretty much gave you the answer. Add a new layer, color it, then play with opacity and blending options until you're happy with it.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/22563/408) will help you out!

Answer (score 1):

I like to do something like this in next way:

1. first of all to add Color Overlay in Styles (black color and Color blend mode). It helps to control desaturation of initial photo.
2. Add a layer with gradient with Color blend mode. To color the image in colors in need.
3. Duplicate my gradient with Multiply blend mode to have control over brightness.

If you have too dark black color you can add Levels as adjusting layer and fix intensity of black.